# Alternative of replication in internet disconnection period of time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I'm looking for an alternative of merge replication that work without internet connection, something like red gate sql data compare but not in uniq direction.

Answer (score 3):

[Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608) is designed explicitly to synchronize occasionally connected data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like utilize Change Data Capture but you will need to roll your own sql statements.

I'm confused why Merge Replication won't work for you here.  If you set the retention period high enough, it can go disconnected and pick up where it left off once connected again.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the merge replication to work with your network disconnects. To get the functionality of the data compare, try using [Interactive Conflict Resolution.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151317%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) This way you can determine the outcome of your conflicts.